# Is there a performance difference for these two Hive queries joining two tables and filtering on a partition key?

Tags: hql, hive

Suppose both table `A` and `B` have `ds` as their partition key.

**Method 1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.userid=B.userid 
WHERE A.ds='2014-01-01' AND B.ds='2014-01-01'
```

**Method 2**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.ds='2014-01-01'
) JOIN (
SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.ds='2014-01-01'
) ON
A.userid=B.userid
```

Will the 2nd query be faster?

I'm wondering how `WHERE` and `JOIN` works in Hive. Is a `where` clause applied to the source table before the join when possible (as long as the clause contains only one table alias, like the ones above), or is it always applied only after the tables are joined (e.g. `A.userid > B.userid` has to be applied after the join)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is actually about predicate pushdown in hive.
Well in the case above the execution will be exactly the same as hive will push the predicate `A.ds='2014-01-01' AND B.ds='2014-01-01'` to the mappers before the join.

In a more general case, the `JOIN` (inner join) is actually pretty easy and can be summed up to :
**If it can push, it will push.**
It can push the predicate when there is only one table involved (`where a.x > 1`) and can't push when there is more than 1 table involved (`A.userid > B.userid`) as the mapper reads a split of one of the tables only..

The more complex part is `OUTER JOIN` and furtunelty explained very clearly [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/OuterJoinBehavior#OuterJoinBehavior-PredicatePushdownRules).

P.S.
predicate pushdown is controlled by `hive.optimize.ppd` which is true by default.

Comment: Thanks dimamah! btw, is there any recommended Hive book that discuss in-depth details like this?

Comment: The oreilly book is the most popular one (google oreilly hive).
Other than that apache's wiki and the hive mailing list (http://hive.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) are good sources for information